# Store the the state of the icon and update it only when conditions are satisfied

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter and i have this code:

```
[if (led.last.contains('1'))...
   [const Icon(
   Icons.fingerprint,
   color: Colors.blue,
   )]
else if (led.last.contains('2')) ...
   [const Icon(
   Icons.fingerprint,
   color: Colors.grey,
   )]
```

edited: I want to store the the state of the icon and update it only when conditions are satisfied.

Please help me.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for, but it sounds like you want a `StatefulWidget` whose `State` has a member that stores the last `Icon`.  Have the `State`'s `build` method use that `Icon`, and update that member only when your conditions are satisfied.

Comment: that is what i meant, how can i do it?

Comment: I update my question

Comment: @jamesdlin is `setstate` possible on this?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use a `StatefulWidget` with `setState`.  If you need more specific help, you should show what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually omit the square brackets if there is only 1 Widget.
You can just add the `else` statement like the `else if` statement.

```
[
    if (led.contains('1'))
      const Icon(
        Icons.fingerprint,
        color: Colors.blue,
      )
    else if (led.contains('2'))
      const Icon(
        Icons.fingerprint,
        color: Colors.grey,
      )
    else
      const Icon(
        Icons.fingerprint,
        color: Colors.blue,
      )
  ]
```

Comment: i edit my question to clarify what i meant

Comment: It is not very clear to me. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I don't find any but I have an arduino that send strings to a flutter app. The string will be added to a list on the flutter app. I have an icon that i would like to update the color if the strings that send by the arduino satisfied its condition.